# How to specifiy comparison for pair?

Tags: c++, std-pair

There is a `pair`

```
pair <string, int> myPair;
```

I have a `vector` of `myPair` objects. I need to convert it to a min-heap using `make_heap` on the second value of `pair` i.e. the integer. How can I do that? I am not sure on how to define the comparison operations.

```
I know I need something like this for heap to operate. But not sure where to put it:

bool operator< (const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const 
{ 
    return p1.second < p2.second;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? A comparison operation is usually just a simple function taking two pair arguments and then returning the usual <0 0 >0-

Comment: No, not a `operator<` but a struct that can be called like a function.. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, `make_heap` has an overload that takes an extra comparision operator, soo...

```
// somewhere in global namespace
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> myPair_type;

struct mypair_comp{
  bool operator()(myPair_type const& lhs, myPair_type const& rhs){
    return lhs.second < rhs.second;
  }
};

// somewhere at your callside
make_heap(first,last,mypair_comp());
```

Comment: Pretty much this, though the lhs & rhs arguments need to be of some type, so either myPair should be a typedef (rather than a variable), or some typedef should be created.

Comment: @John Zwinck: Woops, totally saw that as a typedef, lol.. Edited. :)